# Typescript in Existing React Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, tsx

My question is based on installing typescript in existing React project. It is not related to how to create typescript react!

I have cloned a repo from AWS where there is a react app. Now, I need to make an app using typescript. To install the typescript in React I have run a command "npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest". It is creating typescript in package.json but not creating tsconfig.json file.

My other question is should index.ts file created automatically in React and if it is then how could I convert into lib/index.js within React.

[image: This is current React file structure]

Comment: Here's a good [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-react-app-to-typescript/) about this topic. You may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the article linked in the comments of the post as a guide for migrating from JSreact to TSreact.

For a simple answer, the command below will init a `tsconfig.json` file
with npm as a manager.

```bash
npx tsc --init
```

for yarn

```bash
yarn tsc --init
```

(for completeness).